# Drupal Views argument menu - sending %! to end of URL

Tags: routes, views

Im building this project managment site that uses organic groups to sort and name projects.

So I have example.com/project/6. Where 6 is the organic groups views argument of %1.

What I am struggling to do is be able to create links that send for example 'gallery' to the end of the URL so example.com/project/6/gallery would show the gallery for project 6.

I am trying to create a global menu where all items would work for any organic group you may be within. So if you were within project 5 (http://example.com/project/5) the same menu item of 'Gallery' could be used to display example.com/project/5/gallery.

I have tried with all normal drupal menu methods but %1 is never accepted. The main thing is to be able to send for example '/gallery' to the end of the URL, or use any other method to achieve this.

Hope I have explained myself correctly.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Each segment of the URL is it's own argument. So to get `project/6/gallery` you would have two arguments.

The first argument `%1` (which you already have) is the organic group, the second argument `%2` would be (I assume) a content type argument.

Comment: Thaks for your reply. So would I have to build a 'menu' content type to pass all %2 arguments - so that the same menu could be applied globally to the site within all organic groups?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Menus aren't dynamic. You can use pathauto module to make links using that format, then use the Node Menu settings to add that node to the menu.